# How to use the src file of mediaelementjs player on another frame

Tags: javascript, html, frame, mediaelement.js

I have a `mediaelementjs` player in one frame of a page and another frame has list of audio files.  Can anyone tell me how to access the player from the other frame?

FYI, The frame that has the media player:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('audiox').mediaelementplayer("#audiox");
});
// ]]></script>
```

Thanks
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between windows and frames in a browser is intentionally prevented for security reasons.

You should try to get rid of the frames and join the contents on the same page if you want to pass data.

If you really must keep the frames then I suggest you look into *Javascript* and *Ajax* for safely passing data, but this requires access to a server capable of running server side code like *PHP* or *ASP*.

There might also be a HTML5 feature for passing data as messages between frames. I found an example of how this can be used here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage

Keep in mind to check the origin of the message though to prevent someone from sending messages from an external site.